# Selecting a CheckBox outside of the DataGrid, makes all the row font color in the DataGrid with stock less than minimum quantity have red font

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a WPF DataGrid whose ItemsSource is bound to a list of products in the code behind.

My goal, and I seem to be running in to a lot of issues, is when chkLowInventory is checked, all the rows' font color in the DataGrid with stock <= min_quantity would be changed to Red, then turned back when unchecked.

I've tried getting the DataGridRow using the myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myProduct) but it returns null after a certain number of products, even when I call myDataGrid.UpdateLayout() and myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(myProduct).

Any suggestions would be great.

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgProducts"
              Height="360"
              Margin="20,65,20,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              AlternatingRowBackground="#FFE6E6E6"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Background="#FFC1BFB3"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              FontFamily="Euphemia"
              FontSize="14"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentProduct}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              Style="{DynamicResource BridalStyleDatagridProducts}"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="500"
                                Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                Header="Description" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="200"
                                Binding="{Binding Manufacturer}"
                                Header="Manufacturer" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                                Binding="{Binding RetailPrice,
                                                  StringFormat=c}"
                                Header="Retail Price"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                                Binding="{Binding CurrentStock}"
                                Header="Stock Qty"
                                IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLowInStock}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>

    <CheckBox x:Name="chkLowInventory"
              Margin="490,24,0,0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              BorderThickness="2"
              Content="Show Low Inventory"
              FontFamily="Euphemia"
              FontSize="20"
              Foreground="Black"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=ShowLowInventory}"
              TabIndex="17" />
```

Updated my Code to a MVVM approach. Still having an issue. I was able to get all the rows with low inventory to change the foreground to red. But I want to be able to control when to apply that style with the ShowLowInventory flag.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. All I can hear is "Lack of MVVM", "Lack of DataBinding", "dinousaur winforms approach" kind of sounds everywhere.

Comment: Have to use what was given

Comment: have you tried binding to the foreground property of the column and the is checked property of the check box  and use a converter to go from a bool to a brush?